# My alert button doesn’t close the alert when I press it

Tags: bootstrap-4

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dissmissable" role="alert">  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
This is a success alert
</div>
```

I’ve tried to follow a tutorial, but it doesn’t seem to work properly even after trying to change a few things

Comment: It would help if you link the tutorial too.

Comment: You would have not linked the `bootstrap.min.js` or `jquery.min.js` library to your project. Check out the documentation: *https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/*

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the required meta tags in the head element because when I tried your code it worked for me. When I clicked the cross button the alert went away. If you didn't add the reference to the bootstrap library in the head tag then add it as follows.

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

For more information go to this website https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/.